# Reload and mark a select type with the last insert

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, sql-server

I have a select with all of the results and I want when I insert a new one in the same form refresh the select and mark the last one.

```
Fabricant:<select name="fabricant" >
     <?php 
     $sql = "SELECT * 
     FROM Property
     WHERE PRP_PRP_TYP_Id = 2";
     $result = sqlsrv_query($con, $sql);
     echo "<option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>";
     while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)){
      echo "<option value='".$row['PRP_Id']."'>".$row['PRP_Value']."</option>";
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

And in this code I make the insert sending the value to another page

```
<script>
function fabricant_value(){
$('#fabricant_link').attr('href', 'fabricants_insert.proc.php?new='+$('#add_fabricant').val());
alert("funciona");
}
</script>

<div class="cp_oculta" id="plus1" name="new_fabricant">
        <input type="text" id="add_fabricant" name="add_fabricant"  placeholder="New Fabricant">
        <a onclick="fabricant_value()" id="fabricant_link">
        <i class="fa fa-check-square-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </a>
</div>
```

When the other page receive the value:

```
<?php
$sql_insert = "INSERT INTO Property (PRP_PRP_TYP_Id, PRP_Value) VALUES ('2', '$_REQUEST[new]')";
sqlsrv_query($con, $sql_insert);

echo "<SCRIPT type='text/javascript'> //not showing me this
history.go(-1);
</SCRIPT>";
?>
```

Goes back and the value is on the select as a new option. But I want that **when comes back also appears as selected**. Thanks!

Comment: use ajax to call the php page for inserting new data

Comment: Yes I think so, but I need some orientation or more explaining about how to do it @Rijin